# What's the MySQL Workbench alternative for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm working with SQL Server for the first time and I like using MySQL Workbench. Can anyone recommend a similar application for SQL Server?

Comment: FYI: This will be closed as off-topic because asking for tools, libraries, etc is considered off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Management Studio or SSMS. You can get the express version [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961). Also, if you have a developer/standard or above licence it's already in the setup for the SQL Server.